# IP replace default outbound

Tags: networking, debian, ip

With these two commands I can set the default outbound IP, but how to make them persistent after reboot?

```
# ip route replace default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 src 49.12.112.180
# ip -6 route replace default via fe80::1 dev eth0 src 2a01:4f8:1c17:8010::1
```

Comment: It's a config issue that depends on the distribution you are using, and its version and the tools it's using to configure network (sometimes there are multiple choices). So you should add this information in the question.

Comment: rc.local (ugly mode); if you're on "windows" (aka ubuntu) add the route as a post-up entry into /etc/network/interfaces; OS exact version will help you get a more exact answer

Comment: @A.B what information do you need? I'm not a debian/linux expert

Comment: have added debian as a tag to the question :)

Comment: Then it's probably as @Overmind wrote. Probably because you are probably not using NetworkManager or something else, but probably ifupdown.

Comment: what would the solution be? I'm no linux expert

Comment: You are not stating if the IP address configuration is automatic and only default gateway i wrong or missing, or if you need to set the IP address itself too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the debian you should use the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration file to make the network settings persistent.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is usage of `post-up` statements under interface configuration.

In your case you should write something like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address ...
  post-up /sbin/ip route replace 0/0 via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 src 49.12.112.180 || true

iface eth0 inet6 static
  address ...
  post-up /sbin/ip -6 route replace 0/0 via fe80::1 dev eth0 src 2a01:04f8:1c17:8010::1 || true
```

The `|| true` part is required to avoid errors if something goes wrong in the `post-up` commands.

After edit of the file check the correctness with the `ifquery -v eth0` command.

Comment: Ok, så the `post-up` line will run when the system boot up?

Comment: Yep, the commands will be executed after the interface activation. The `auto eth0` means activate interface after system boot.

Comment: ok, another thing. I can see your query/command is a bit different. Mine `... replace default via ...` vs yours `... replace 0/0 via ...` Whats the difference?

Comment: There isn't the difference. The `default` is an alias from the `/etc/networks` file. The `0/0` is an shortcut of `0.0.0.0/0` (for ipv4) or `0::/0` (for ipv6). Feel free use of any form of command, what is suitable for you.